# How to make the camera follow an object's trajectory in 2.8?

Tags: animation, camera

Hi everyone i'm trying to get my camera to follow an object, after looking at tutorials I've tried using the constraint "track to" however it only make the camera look at the object not move along with it.

Comment: Copy Location constraint? Parent it to the object? It also depends on how it is supposed to follow...

Comment: Copy location worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Give your object a *Copy Location* constraint with your object as *Target*, click on the *Offset* option so that you can still move your camera the way you want.